# Trying to restrict other sound when other sound is playing

Tags: android

I am trying to make a sound wait to play if another sound is currently playing. But, the code I wrote doesn't execute.

```
 public class Transportation extends AppCompatActivity {

        private MediaPlayer sound,sound1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.transportation);

            sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vatunabus);
            final ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vatunabussound);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                        sound.stop();
                        sound.release();
                    }
                    else if(sound.isPlaying()){
                        sound.pause();

                    }
                    else {
                        sound.start();

                    }
                }
            });            


            sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.varowlsanabus);
            final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.firstbussound);
            imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(sound.isPlaying()){
                        sound1.stop();
                        sound1.release();
                    }
                    else if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                        sound1.pause();

                    }
                    else {
                        sound1.start();

                    }

                }
            });         

        }

    }
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: There must be a compilation error then. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: @AbdulKawee.... actually there is not error during compilation. I want a sound to wait for its turn to play even if it was clicked  while another sound is currently playing. It does not give desired output.

Comment: @Rohit5k2... actually there is not error during compilation. I want a sound to wait for its turn to play even if it was clicked  while another sound is currently playing. It does not give desired output.

Comment: It must be playing straight away because that is how you have coded it. On the click you need to check if something is playing. If yes then you need to add the new sound in a variable and wait for the old sound to finish (find remaining duration somehow). Start a timer with the remaining duration and play the new sound after timer finishes.

Comment: @Rohit5k2...There are two ImageView with different two sounds. On clicking the sound i want a media to play and before the sound  finish playing if i click on the sound1 the code should restrict the sound1 from playing because the sound is currently playing. I am newbie to android, so, can you write me the code?